# Drush, Omega 4 - Does not seem to recognize Drupal site

Tags: drush, theming

I've installed Drupal 7, Drush 7.0 and the Omega 4 theme. I'm using MAMP. Drush does not seem to recognize the /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newsite/ as a Drupal folder (which it is). I'm attempting to create an Omega subtheme with the command line.:

drush omega-wizard

I then receive the following error:
[image]

And then this when I debug:

[image]

Thoughts? Help!!!

-Logan

Comment: Did you try the advice in http://drupal.org/node/1428638?

Comment: Yes, I did. No luck. This is a tough one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what has caused this but the solution is:

1) Enable the Omega theme (`drush en omega`) and set as default (`drush vset theme_default omega`)

2) Run `drush omega-wizard`